# Concatenate clips with as little code as possible in AviSynth+

Tags: avisynth

I am new to AviSynth+. I am concatenating 9 clips, trimming the first and last, fading in the first and fading out the last, and cross-dissolving between clips. This code works:

```
audio=ffaudiosource("F:\_DSC001.MOV")
video=FFMS2("F:\_DSC001.MOV")
start=AudioDub(audio, video)
clip1=Trim(start, 3600, 30000)

audio=ffaudiosource("F:\_DSC002.MOV")
video=FFMS2("F:\_DSC002.MOV")
clip2=AudioDub(audio, video)

... same for clips 3-8 ...

audio=ffaudiosource("F:\_DSC009.MOV")
video=FFMS2("F:\_DSC009.MOV")
clip9=Trim(AudioDub(audio, video), 0, 22575)

FadeIn(clip1, 100)
Dissolve(last, clip2, 50)
Dissolve(last, clip3, 50)
Dissolve(last, clip4, 50)
Dissolve(last, clip5, 50)
Dissolve(last, clip6, 50)
Dissolve(last, clip7, 50)
Dissolve(last, clip8, 50)
Dissolve(last, clip9, 50)
FadeOut(last, 100)
```

It's quite verbose and repetitive. I wonder if some pre-processor script can take some of these parameters and arguments and produce the above AviSynth+ script.

Does such a pre-processor exist, or could the AviSynth+ script be optimized or improved?

Answer (score 2):

```
function SegmentedDissolve(string base, int first_val, int last_val, string format, int dissolve_length ){
    filename = base + string(first_val, format) + ".MOV"
    result = FFMS2(filename)
    return (first_val < last_val) \
        ? Dissolve(result, SegmentedDissolve(base, first_val+1, last_val, format, dissolve_length), dissolve_length) \
        : result
}

SegmentedDissolve("F:\_DSC", 1, 9, "%03.0f", 50).Trim(3600, yyy).FadeIn(100).FadeOut(100)
```

You would need to figure out what value `yyy` needs to be for the concatenated clip. If the first clip needs to be trimmed on both sides, then the first clip should not be included in the function (start `first_val` at 2), and instead get loaded, processed, and concatenated manually.

As a note, the FFMS2 function also loads up any audio found in the specified clip, so you do not need to dub it unless you are doing processing on it first.

Comment: I lost access to AviSynth on Windows and could not install it on Azure. I may try this code on macOS now that AviSynth is compatible.